# Is it possible to setup Razor code highlights in Visual Studio 2022 to match Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2022

VS2022 version: 17.5.1

Trying to move to VS2022, and I've noticed that the razor syntax highlighting has changed (imo for the worse). I'm wondering if it's possible to move back to the way it was in 2019?

Specifically, Razor bits in 2019 were marked differently than surrounding areas with a silver background and their own text colour. In VS2022 it seems to only differentiate via the @ symbol, and worst of all, takes on the text colour of surrounding blocks (see below for the razor code inside of a string).

I've tried the font colours option - specifically, the Razor Code Background setting, which isn't present in my options in VS2019. However, when I change it (again, in VS2022), **it updates the way Razor is displayed in VS2019, while ignoring it in VS2022!!!**

VS2019:

[image]

VS2022:

[image]

Comment: *it updates the way Razor is displayed in VS2019, while ignoring it in VS2022!!!* No clue why thats happening.  Maybe try deleting the .vs folder and then reopen the solution in Visual Studio 2022.  Otherwise, you found the correct color settings that you need to tweak.

Comment: @TimothyG. Can confirm that deleting .vs folder didn't do anything. Can also confirm that this happens for a brand new project, so it doesn't seem to be related to transitioning from VS2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, this has now been fixed as of Visual Studio 17.8+.
You can now change this setting under Tools/Options/Text Editor/Razor/Advanced
[image]

Comment: I prefer this solution to not sacrifice the latest improvements. See the comment under the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-the-new-razor-editor-in-visual-studio-2022/) we can see:

> Default colors have been updated in the new Razor editor. A major
> difference in this area is the removal of the code background
> highlight that was present in previous versions.

If you want to setup Razor code highlights in Visual Studio 2022 to match Visual Studio 2019,you can revert back to the legacy editor by going to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Advanced and select True from the dropdown` next to Use legacy Razor editor for ASP.NET Core.  Then reopen the Visual Studio.
[image]

[image]
Keep in mind that the legacy Razor editor will have limited functionality and not include the productivity improvements mentioned in this post that we added in the new Razor editor.

Comment: This is not recommended by Microsoft btw, if you want to get the latest improvements:  _"If you find that your developer productivity is limited in the new editor, you can revert back to the legacy editor. Keep in mind that the legacy Razor editor will have limited functionality and not include the productivity improvements mentioned in this post that we added in the new Razor editor."_  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-the-new-razor-editor-in-visual-studio-2022/